# State Management with ViewModel on Android when on a flow

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-navigation

Basically I have a state management system using `ViewModel` that looks like this:

```kotlin
class ViewModelA: ViewModel() {

    private val repository: RepositoryA by inject()

    private val _stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<ViewState>()
    val stateLiveData: LiveData<ViewState> get() = _stateLiveData

    private val _eventLiveData = SingleLiveEvent<ViewEvent>()
    val eventLiveData: LiveData<ViewEvent> get() = _eventLiveData

    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
        _stateLiveData.postValue(ViewState.Error)
    }

    fun loadList() {
        if (_stateLiveData.value is ViewState.Loading) return
        launch(exceptionHandler) {
            _stateLiveData.run {
                value = ViewState.Loading
                value = repository.getDocumentList().let {
                    if (it.isEmpty()) ViewState.Error
                    else ViewState.Data(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I am sharing a `ViewModel` with several `Fragments`, it becomes bigger and bigger. I am looking for a solution for this, because I don't want to centralize all the logic for an entire application flow inside a `ViewModel` and I also don't want to pass arguments here and there all the time.

PS: Sorry about my bad english.
Edit: Clarify a bit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question. However, if your question was as follows:

> How can I share the same `ViewModel` Object and use it inside multiple `Fragment`s.

You can check the documentation of [ViewModelProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider?hl=en) which is a utility class that provides `ViewModel`s for a specific scope like `Activity`.

Following is an example code of the usage of `ViewModelProvider` within two `Fragment`s that will be created and used in the same `Activity` object:

```
// An example ViewModel
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val intLiveData = MutableLiveData<Int>() // an example LiveData field

}
```

```
// the first fragment
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = requireActivity().let { activity ->
            ViewModelProvider(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

```
// the other fragment
class Fragment2 : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = requireActivity().let { activity ->
            ViewModelProvider(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to edit it to be more clear but about sharing a `ViewModel` I am currently using Koin's `sharedViewModel`. Thanks anyways!